# Duplicate fields when using ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I upgraded from Django 1.10 to 1.11 and now two of my models which previously worked are causing errors.  They are the only two models that have a `ManyToManyField` that includes a `related_name` attribute.  I have another `ManyToManyField` without a `related_name` and it works fine.

The error that gets thrown is misleading:

> `<class 'hadotcom.admin.CaseStudyAdmin'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[0][1]'`

I've found other SO posts that reference that error and confirmed that none of them match my issue.

If I comment out the entire line it passes the check.  I tried adding a `through` attribute and that didn't help.

Sample code (using Mezzanine):

```py
class CaseStudyPage(Page):
  industries = models.ManyToManyField("IndustryPage", blank=True, related_name="industry_set", through="CaseStudyIndustries")

class CaseStudyAdmin(HaPageAdmin):
  inlines = (Foo, Bar,)
```

Happy to fill in any blanks, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If `"IndustryPage"` is a model than remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Ahtisham, but I have it in quotes so that I can lazy load it since it is defined later in the file.

Comment: Show us `CaseStudyAdmin` code.

Comment: What you see is what is there.  The two inlines are basic models and even if I remove them it throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `ContentTypedAdmin` in `Mezzanine` adds `ManyToMany` fields in subclasses twice. I haven't investigated exactly why it happens. A possible solution is to alter the last two lines of `ContentTypedAdmin.__init__()` to:

```
if not hasattr(field, "translated_field") and field.name not in self.fieldsets[0][1]["fields"]:
    self.fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(3, field.name)
```